# distributing part of a vector to slave processes

Tags: c++, vector, mpi

Using C++ and OpenMPI I'd like to create a vector and then in the master process distribute parts of the vector evenly to the slave processes to be processed.  So if the vector has 100 integers and there are 5 slave processes then each slave process would be sent a vector of 20 integers.

Below is the code I was trying but it's not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int rank, size, tag, rc, i;
MPI_Status status;
vector<int> vec(100);
vector<int> split_vec;

rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
rc = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
rc = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
tag=7;

random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](){ return dis(gen); });
// 100 ints / 5 slave processes
int split_size = vec.size() / size;
// split_size = size of vector of ints that each slave process should get
int offset = 0;
int j = 0;
int max = split_size;
if (rank==0) {
// master process
     for (int i=1; i<size; ++i){
            split_vec.clear();
            while(j < max){
                int elements = i_j + offset;
                split_vec.push_back(vec[elements]);
                j++;
            }
            max = max + split_size;
            offset = offset + split_size;
     MPI_Send(&split_vec[0], split_vec.size(), MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else{
   // slaves processes
   MPI_Recv(&split_vec[0], split_vec.size(), MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   // process the vector
}
   MPI_Finalize();
}// main
```

When I run the code above I get the following error:

```
[comp-01:7562] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[comp-01:7562] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[comp-01:7562] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[comp-01:7562] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

It seems to be working it's way through the `vector<int> vec(100)` vector properly, grabbing the first twenty integers, next twenty, etc.  But I think it's crashing because I keep overwriting the elements in `split_vec` and the garage values are making it crash.  When I print the vectors because I send it below is what is printed before it crashes.

```
0 64 0 33 0 1819240283 808662067 976302125 892679984 2121015 0 49 0 -773125744 32554 0 0 -773125760 32554 0 0
```

Even though there are no `0` or negative numbers in the `vec` vector.  So I tried to fix this by adding the `split_vec.clear();` code but that doesn't seem to work either.

Below is what I used to compile and run it.

```
mpic++ -std=c++11 prog.cpp -o prog.o
mpirun -np 6 prog.o  // 5 slave process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes are needed so as to make `MPI_Recv()` successful:

- In the code you posted, `split_vec.size()` is 0 in `MPI_Recv()` since `split_vec` is not populated yet. Hence, `MPI_Recv()` will receive a message, but the vector will not be modified.
- **The receive buffer must be allocated first.** In the present case, it means that `split_vec.reserve(split_size);` must be added prior to the call to `MPI_Recv(&split_vec[0],MPI_INT,split_size,...);`. Indeed, the method [`vector::reserve(size_type n)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) will increase the capacity of the vector to at least `n` elements. As noticed by @Zulan , using [`split_vec.resize(split_size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) is more correct as it also updates the size of the vector.

Finally, the following code does the trick:

```
split_vec.resize(split_size);
MPI_Recv(&split_vec[0],MPI_INT,split_vec.size(),...);
```

Here is a corrected code. Notice that the indexes used to populate the array on rank 0 had to be modified. Compile it by `mpiCC main.cpp -o main -std=c++11 -Wall`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size, tag;
    MPI_Status status;
    vector<int> vec(100);
    vector<int> split_vec;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    tag=7;

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](){ return dis(gen); });
    // 100 ints / 5 slave processes
    int split_size = vec.size() / size;
    // split_size = size of vector of ints that each slave process should get
    int offset = 0;
    if (rank==0) {
        // master process
        for (int i=1; i<size; ++i){
            split_vec.clear();
            split_vec.reserve(split_size);
            int j=0; // added j=0
            while(j < split_size){
                int elements = j + offset;
                split_vec.push_back(vec[elements]);
                j++;
            }
            //max =  split_size; 
            offset = offset + split_size;
            MPI_Send(&split_vec[0], split_vec.size(), MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    else{
        // slaves processes
        split_vec.resize(split_size);
        MPI_Recv(&split_vec[0], split_vec.size(), MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // until receive is complete, split_vec.size()==0
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}// main
```

Finally, you are going to enjoy the function [`MPI_Scatter()`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) which exactly does what you want to do!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;

    vector<int> vec(100);
    vector<int> split_vec;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](){ return dis(gen); });
    // 100 ints / 5 slave processes
    int split_size = vec.size() / size;
    // split_size = size of vector of ints that each slave process should get


    split_vec.resize(split_size);
    MPI_Scatter(&vec[0],split_size,MPI_INT,&split_vec[0],split_size,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
}// main
```

Comment: You cannot use `std::vector::reserve` here! While this will not crash, the vector will still have a `size` of 0 after the `MPI_Recv` / `MPI_Scatter` call! Use `resize` instead.

Comment: "the number of items sent must match the number of items to be received" This is not correct. The standard (3.2.4) only requires: "The length of the received message must be **less than or equal** to the length of the receive buffer."

Comment: @Zulan : thanks for having signaled these mistakes in my answer! I still have plenty of things to learn about MPI...